# Открытие модальных окон

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Всем доброго времени суток. В скрытое поле модальной формы отправляется id записи, но содержимое модального окна не соответствует этому id. Как это исправить?

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hotel");
$result=mysqli_query($con,"Select * from room where  (datestart < '$datearrive' or dateend >'$dateliave') ");

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$id_room=$row['id_room'];
$adres=$row['name'];
$price=$row['price'];

?>
<section class='section section-md bg-secondary-4 text-center text-sm-left' style='padding-top: 65px;'>
  <div class='shell'>
    <div class='range range-50 range-md-justify range-sm-reverse'>
      <div class='cell-sm-6 cell-md-5'>
      <?php
    
    echo"  <h2 ><a href='book.php?room=$id_room'>$adres</a></h2>";
    ?>
        <p></p>
 
<button data-room-id="<?php echo $id_room; ?>" class="btn btn-primary open-modal">Забронировать</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
 
<?php
}
?>
<script>
    $('.open-modal').click(function(){
     
        let roomId = $(this).attr('data-room-id');
 
        $('#data-room-id').val(roomId);
        
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    })
</script>

    <form action="reserve.php">
<input type="hidden" id="data-room-id">  
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade"  >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      
        <h4 class='modal-title'><?php echo "$adres"; ?> </h4>
    
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
             
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
    
        <button class="button button-primary button-square button-block button-effect-ujarak" type="submit" name="submit" ><span>check availability </span></button>    
  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: А что такое  $('#data-room-id') ?

Comment: @Quazimorda идентификатор скрытого поля

Comment: Сорри, не обратил внимание. Я бы java-script для порядка разместил под формой, в которой он присваивает значение скрытому элементу формы.

Comment: @Quazimorda посмотрел через alert id правильный передаётся. Как сделать чтобы заголовок модалки соответствовал заголовку в БД?

Comment: У вас из базы данных прилетает один набор данных (одна строка) или несколько?

Comment: @Quazimorda Несколько

Comment: Ещё один глупый вопрос: а в сформированных секциях у вас на разных кнопках разные id привязаны?

Comment: @Quazimorda разные <button data-room-id="<?php echo $id_room; ?>" class="btn btn-primary open-modal">Забронировать</button>

Comment: Как создаются кнопки в цикле я видел. Всё-таки, я бы java-script для порядка разместил под формой, в которой он присваивает значение скрытому элементу формы.